# Why Ajax request is always showing error message while the JSon is always returning true?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am not getting why this error occurring. I have a method named SitePlanSaveTask which creates new plan and returns Json True if it is successfully saved. Now when I debug the method the plan successfully saves and Json always return true. But in the view it is always giving error message. My question is if my Json returns true then why is it not going to the Ajax request condition.

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {

        if (!User.IsInRole("Management"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error");
        }

        ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(db.Project, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        ViewBag.EndDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        ViewBag.PlanDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        var status = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Active", Value = "A" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Inactive", Value = "I" }, }, "Value", "Text");
        ViewBag.Status = status;
        List<ProjectTask> taskList = db.ProjectTask.ToList();
        ViewBag.ProjectTask = taskList;
        return View();
    }

  public JsonResult SitePlanSaveTask(string name)
    {
        ProjectTask projectTask = new ProjectTask();
        projectTask.Name = name;
        var check = db.ProjectTask.Where(x => x.Name == name).Count();
        bool flag = false;
        if (check == 0)
        {
            db.ProjectTask.Add(projectTask);

            flag = db.SaveChanges() > 0;
        }

        return Json(new { flag = flag, Id = projectTask.Id }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View:

```
  $("#btnAddTask").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/ProjectSitePlanTasks/SitePlanSaveTask",
        data: {
            name: $("#TName").val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result.flag)
            {
                alert("Record saved successfully!");
                window.location = "/ProjectSitePlanTasks/Create";

            }
            else
            {
                alert("Saving failed!");
            }

        },
       error: function (result)
       {
            alert('error');
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Start by removing `contentType: "application/json",`. Which error message are you getting - _Saving failed!_ or _error_?

Comment: And the whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page. The fact you have `window.location = "...";` in the callback means that you should not be using ajax. Just make a normal submit and save you self the time of writing this unnecessary script.

Comment: @StephenMuecke But if the form fails he needs to stay there in the page. Even Facebook signup page is working the same way i think !

Comment: @StephenMuecke I do not want to load the entire page when I am creating new Task. But here when I save new task the entire page is loading. If I remove window.location = "..." then the data saves but for seeing the updated data I again need to refresh the entire page. So what can I do to ignore the page refresh and updates the data without loading the entire page!

Comment: @vipincp, That is why your check `ModelState` and if invalid you return the view so validation messages etc are displayed and the user can correct them. The current code does not even indicate what the error is or what the user is supposed to do about it :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i think you mentioned my name by mistake :) or is it a reply for my comment ?

Comment: `window.location=".."` is refreshing the whole page :) If you want to stay on the same page and just update part of the DOM, then you just do that in the `success` callback. You have not indicated what you want to update, but assuming you want to display the new `Id` value, then it might be something like `$(someElement).val(result.Id);` if the element is an input

Comment: @vipincp - it was a reply to your comment :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yeah that is right stephen. I just want to point out there are scenarios which we need to use ajax even if a redirection is there on SUCCESS. I understand your concern. Thanks  for pointing out.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to create new Task and showing it instant on the list. The main problem I am facing now is that when I save the task, the latest task is not added to the list on the page until the page is refreshed. Mentioning that I have already removed the window.locaton but the problem is still there.

Comment: I can only assume you have a table that displays the current tasks and want to add a new row to that table? And if that is the case, then you just do it in the `success` callback. But impossible to show you the code unless we see you current view. And FGS, get rid of all that dreadful use of `ViewBag` and use a view model, and pass the view model to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all controller action method is httpget. so you have to convert it to httppost by using below code snippet.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SitePlanSaveTask(string name)
{
 ....
 ....
}
```

Comment: Now saves successfully but the entire page is loading. I do not want to load the entire page when I am creating new Task

Comment: I think  "btnAddTask " is submit type button. it should not be submit type button.

Comment: Then what type it will be can you please tell? @Jayesh

Comment: you can set type="button"

Comment: But my type was already set to button type.  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddTask">Save</button>

Comment: because of below code line it refresh the full page
window.location = "/ProjectSitePlanTasks/Create";

Comment: @Nabid, It should definitely be a submit button (and that way you can check if the form is valid (and cancel it if not so that validation messages are displayed (your use of `e.preventDefault();` meams a normal submit will not be made)

Comment: Will I remove preventDefault and make the button type as submit? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Change the button to a submit button, but leave the `e.preventDefault()` so that it cancels the default submit action of your form.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Changed it according to your comment. But it remains with the same problem. Page does not load as I removed window.location but the newly added data is not also showing in the TaskList which is on the same page. When I create new Task, the newly added task is added to the Task List.

Comment: @Nabid, You need to show your view code as I noted previously and explain what you want to update. I cant add an answer that just makes wild guesses about what you want to update in the view. And that will also give me the chance to explain all the other bad code and poor practices your doing

Comment: @StephenMuecke Where will I give the view? Will I edit the description and adding there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159444/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-nabid).

Answer (score 0):

Try `JSON.stringify(result)`. Then take `result.flag` . This could be working.

Answer (score 0):

Have try it?

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SitePlanSaveTask(string name){
...
}
```

Comment: Yes I have tried the solution now the page is loading when I create new task. But I do not want the page to be loaded when I create new task

Comment: By th code  ` window.location = "/ProjectSitePlanTasks/Create";`  it always refresh the page,and load page again. Maybe you should try another way like just bind data in this page instead of  call the function `Create`.

Comment: like call  `LoadData`  in ajax.  `public ActionResult LoadData(){    # do  BindData         
              ViewBag.ProjectTask = taskList;
            return View("your page address"); }`